# Choosing Donuts so that No One Goes Hungry?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose there are 10 donuts and 3 friends. Friend 1 comes to the table and eats some donuts, followed by Friend 2, followed by Friend 3.

I tried to write this using these logical conditions:

- Friend 1 comes and eats some donuts (some number "n1" from 0 and 10)
- Friend 2 comes and eats some donuts (some number "n2" between 0 and 10 - n1)
- Friend 3 comes and eats some donuts (some number "n3" between 0 and 10 - n1 - n2)

Are there any general combinatorial formulas that allow us to determine:

- Case 1: How many different ways could the friends have eaten the donuts provided that each friend at least had 1 donut and no donuts are remaining on the table? (e.g. Friend 1 ate 5 donuts, Friend 2 ate 4 donuts, Friend 3 ate 1 donut)
- Case 2: How many different ways could the friends have eaten the donuts provided that each friend at least had 1 donut and it is not necessary that some donuts are remaining on the table? (e.g. Friend 1 ate 3 donuts, Friend 2 ate 5 donuts, Friend 3 ate 1 donut)
- Case 3: How many different ways could the friends have eaten the donuts provided that some friends might have not eaten any donuts and no donuts are left on the table? (e.g. Friend 1 ate 6 donuts, Friend 2 ate 0 donuts, Friend 3 ate 4 donuts)
- Case 4: How many different ways could the friends have eaten the donuts provided that some friends might have not eaten any donuts and it is not necessary that some  donuts are left on the table? (e.g. Friend 1 ate 6 donuts, Friend 2 ate 0 donuts, Friend 3 ate 2 donuts)
- Case 5: How many different ways could the friends have eaten the donuts provided Friend 2 ate 3 donuts, the other 2 friends at least 1 donut and no donuts are remaining on the table?
- Case 6: How many different ways could the friends have eaten the donuts provided Friend 2 ate 3 donuts, the other 2 friends at least 1 donut and it is not necessary that some donuts are remaining on the table?
- Case 7: How many different ways could the friends have eaten the donuts provided Friend 1 ate at least 2 donuts,  Friend 2 ate 3 donuts, the other friend at least 1 donut and it is not necessary that some donuts are remaining on the table?

These are some general combinatorial problems that I thought of - each of them would have a large number "ways" in which the donuts could have been eaten. For example:

- Case 1, Way 1: F1 = 3, F2 = 5, F3 = 3
- Case 1, Way 2: F1 = 8, F2 = 1, F3 = 1
- Case 1, Way 3: F1 = 1, F2 = 6, F3 = 3
- etc.

**For these types of problems, are there any general combinatorial formulas I adapt to figure out how many different ways the donuts can be eaten relative to some constraints?**

Thank you!

Comment: Are you familiar with the stars-and-bars technique? There's also a trick of considering the box of donuts itself as taking any remaining donuts.

Comment: I have not heard of this technique! I am searching it on google right now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KyleMiller mentioned, you need to know [Stars & Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))

Case $1$: Direct Application. Ans = $\binom{10 - 1}{3 - 1} = 36$

Case $2$: We can iterate on the total number of donuts eaten. Ans = $\binom{10 - 1}{3 - 1} + \binom{9 - 1}{3 - 1} + \cdots + \binom{3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{10}{3} = 120$ (Hockey-Stick Identity)

Case $3$: Direct Application. Ans = $\binom{10 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = 66$

Case $4$: Similar to Case $2$. Ans = $\binom{10 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} + \binom{9 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} + \cdots + \binom{0 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{13}{3}$ (Hockey-Stick Identity)

Case $5$: Subtract Friend $2$ donuts. $7$ donuts left. Now, direct application. Ans = $\binom{7 - 1}{2 - 1} = 6$

Case $6$: Similarly iterate on the number of donuts after subtracting Friend $2$'s share. Ans = $\binom{7 - 1}{2 - 1} + \binom{6 - 1}{2 - 1} + \cdots + \binom{2 - 1}{2 - 1} = \binom{7}{2} = 21$ (Hockey-Stick Identity)

Case $7$: Subtract Friend $2$'s donuts. $7$ donuts left. Subtract $2$ donuts of Friend $1$ and $1$ donut from Friend $3$. Remaining = $4$. Now, we need to find the number of ways to distribute at-most $4$ donuts among Friend $1$ and $3$ (they may receive $0$). Ans = $\binom{4 + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} + \binom{3 + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} + \cdots + \binom{0 + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} = \binom{6}{2} = 15$ (Hockey-Stick Identity)